# What should we do with the development tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently [development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) is used for questions about the [development of emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-is-the-gnu-emacs-source-code-organized), questions about using [emacs for development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/384/command-to-automatically-define-a-resource-variable-in-an-android-project) (which may be a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), along with [programming](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming)), and [setting up a development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/349/how-can-i-set-emacs-up-for-ios-development-with-swift) environment in emacs.

Is there a better system we can use for tagging these different types of questions? Perhaps add [emacs-development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-development) for questions specific to developing emacs?

Comment: Are the 2nd and 3rd examples any different?

Comment: I may have chosen bad examples but I think there's a difference between I'm using emacs to develop for x, how can I do y and how can I use emacs to develop for x?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. But still, I believe that the main divergence here is the dichotomy you imply in your last sentence: developing emacs vs developing with emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep general development questions (the 2nd and 3rd) as [development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) and use [emacs-development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-development) for any question relating to the development of Emacs.

I wouldn't go so far as to define either of these as "meta-tags". It might be a meta-tag on SO, but development is only one of emacs' many uses. Specifying a question is about development does indeed narrow down the field **a lot**.

<sub>As for [programming](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming), it may be a synonym of [development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development), but that's another question altogether.</sub>