# A tag for internal features?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a few questions dealing with different aspects of the "behind-the-scenes" of emacs:

- [Are there any benefits of compiling Emacs with one graphical toolkit opposed to another?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2263/184)
- [How is the GNU Emacs source code organized?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/301/184)
- [What algorithm does sort use?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3701/184)
- [What piece of code in Emacs makes `line-number-mode` print "??" as line number in buffers with long lines?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3824/50)

They all deal with different aspects of Emacs, but they all have that in common that they are asking about what is not presented to the user: compilation flags, source code organization or implementation of C built-ins.

This was already somewhat mentioned in this question: [What should we do with the development tag?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/110/184)

However, I feel that our toolbox of tags is still insufficient. The first question of my list is tagged with [compilation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilation), which is inappropriate, and [byte-compilation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/byte-compilation) would only be slightly better. I am going to suggest the creation of [emacs-compilation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-compilation) for this question.

But this tag (if accepted) will not host that many questions, and I think the questions above have really more in common than the 0 tags that they share (not that hard, eh? ^^).

Hence my suggestion/question: should we create a tag for this kind of questions, dealing with how emacs works behind the emacs-lisp?

Examples of topics belonging to that tag (including the ones above)

- compilation flags
- emacs source
- C built-ins (not how to use them, but what's inside)
- low-level dependencies
- differences between emacs builds (e.g. emacsw32 vs cygwin emacs)

If so, I suggest the name [internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internals), because (imo) it speaks both to the expert and the newcomer, and [it is the name that the manual uses](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/GNU-Emacs-Internals.html). And it is less prone to errors than e.g. [c-source-code](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-source-code) would be.

Other suggestions could be [emacs-core](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-core), [emacs-source](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-source)...

Comment: emacs-core and emacs-source would be way too broad. Essentially anything that's not an external package is part of emacs-core (ido, dired, f90-mode). In fact, even GNU Elpa packages are part of GNU Emacs per se, so people would be entitled to think emacs-source includes them.

Comment: That said, I do agree with this tag idea. Perhaps emacs-internals might be easier to find than internals.

Comment: I don't have much of an opinion about the general question. Wrt `emacs-compilation`, I think maybe `building-emacs` would be a better term. It's slightly more general (can include platform, `make`, and build-script questions etc.), and it's generally the term used on `emacs-devel@gnu.org`. Compilation is a big part of building, but it's not all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreeing with Malabarba and posting as answer to allow for voting opinions:

- [emacs-internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-internals) used as the tag to ensure clarity

  - Set [internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internals) as a synonym if we end up having it used as well/instead
  - Not for built-in packages/ELPA
  - Not for `How do I use YYY` where `YYY` is in C-source (unless asking about 
    implementation of.
- [emacs-compilation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-compilation) used for any issues that relate to compiling Emacs

  - How do I compile Emacs on `X`
  - I get `error ...` when compiling, how do I fix/trace this issue
  - What are the differences in compilation using `compile-flag XXX vs YYY`
  - For questions relating to `cd /path/to/emacs/src && make`
  - Not for using Emacs to compile other languages
  - Not for telling Emacs to byte-compile.

[emacs-internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-internals) would be a good tag for those dealing with implementation of Emacs.
[emacs-compilation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-compilation) would be a good tag for those dealing with what results from compilation, or is needed for compilation.

There will likely be overlap between the two (and probably [emacs-development](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-development)),

Comment: Just for clarity, is your last paragraph aimed at questions like "I have error XXX when compiling emacs, what can I do?"? Do you include questions like the one about x toolkits in this category?

Comment: For clarity (editing in): yes to both.  Questions regarding errors compiling emacs, compile flags, how to compile on system `X` would fit under that.

Comment: Hm. I do see your point, and the limit is much easier to place this way, to be fair, but I believe this limit will quickly lead to problems. For example, "what difference is there between compiling with library X or Y?" would be `emacs-compilation`. But then the more specific "is there a performance difference between function f defined using library X or Y?" would also be `emacs-compilation`... And then questions about the implementation or performances of a specific C function would be tagged differently, depending on how deeply they depend on external libraries (...)

Comment: (...) But I agree that "there will probably be an overlap", no matter what definition we choose. If we agree that this implies that in overlap cases, either tag (or both) is valid, there isn't any real problem.

Comment: I would say all (including development) could be valid in some cases.  Tag it appropriately to show this overlap (since each also will have cases where the others do not) and it will be fine.

Comment: Before this can be applied, we need an actual definition of what the emacs-internals tag actually applies to. Note that this answer only defines the tag in terms what it *isn't*. Furthermore, the question defined it mostly in terms of examples. Both are a start, but neither are enough. We need a wiki excerpt.