# What tag wiki do we use for [emacs-internals]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Also see: [A tag for internal features?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/222/50)

---

As per the discussion above, we've created the [emacs-internals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-internals) tag.

However, this tag needs a more solid definition of what it applies to.

Currently, we have:

> different aspects of the "behind-the-scenes" of emacs

and also:

> - Not for built-in packages/ELPA
> - Not for `How do I use YYY` where `YYY` is in C-source (unless asking about 
>     implementation of.

**But this is not enough, we need a proper definition, preferably in the form of a tag wiki. Any proposals?**

It's ok if the proposed definition excludes one of the questions it's currently used on, as long as it makes sense.